# add plugin to build.gradl in android sudio

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I want to add a plugin to the Gradle file as shown below in Android Studio, but this is not possible in Android Studio version "El 2022.1.1", thank you in advance for your help.

```
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
    apply plugin: 'android.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
```

I even acted this way

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'android.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}
```

But the Gradle file gives an error

Comment: Are you using goovy or kotlin? And what's the error you are getting?

Comment: @SreeramSunkara Im using Kotlin, In short, the error states that this is not correct Syntax

Comment: Check this and this shows the syntaxes for kotlin gradle: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:binary_plugins